# python pandas - TypeError when parsing JSON: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, pandas, typeerror

The records in the JSON file look like this (please note what "nutrients" looks like):

```
{
"id": 21441,
"description": "KENTUCKY FRIED CHICKEN, Fried Chicken, EXTRA CRISPY,
Wing, meat and skin with breading",
"tags": ["KFC"],
"manufacturer": "Kentucky Fried Chicken",
"group": "Fast Foods",
"portions": [
{
"amount": 1,
"unit": "wing, with skin",
"grams": 68.0
},
...
],
"nutrients": [
{
"value": 20.8,
"units": "g",
"description": "Protein",
"group": "Composition"
},
{'description': 'Total lipid (fat)',
'group': 'Composition',
'units': 'g',
'value': 29.2}
...
]
}
```

The following is the code from the book exercise*. It includes some wrangling and assembles the nutrients for each food into a single large table:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

db = pd.read_json("foods-2011-10-03.json")

nutrients = []

for rec in db:
     fnuts = pd.DataFrame(rec["nutrients"])
     fnuts["id"] = rec["id"]
     nutrients.append(fnuts)
```

However, I get the following error and I can't figure out why:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-ac63a09efd73> in <module>()
      1 for rec in db:
----> 2     fnuts = pd.DataFrame(rec["nutrients"])
      3     fnuts["id"] = rec["id"]
      4     nutrients.append(fnuts)
      5

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

*This is an example from the book [Python for Data Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449319793)

Comment: Your JSON is not valid (and even when one corrects the quotes and removes the dots, it cannot be loaded by `pd.read_json`). Please submit data we can actually see your problem on.

Comment: @Amadan, here is the link to the data: https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book/blob/master/ch07/foods-2011-10-03.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for rec in db` iterates over *column names*. To iterate over rows,

```
for id, rec in db.iterrows():
    fnuts = pd.DataFrame(rec["nutrients"])
    fnuts["id"] = rec["id"]
    nutrients.append(fnuts)
```

This is a bit slow though (all the dicts that need constructing). `itertuples` is faster; but since you only care about two series, iterating over series directly is probably fastest:

```
for id, value in zip(db['id'], db['nutrients']):
    fnuts = pd.DataFrame(value)
    fnuts["id"] = id
    nutrients.append(fnuts)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine! Have there been changes in how this iteration works since the book was written or should this be added to book's errata?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know too much about Pandas history, and I haven't read the book.

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly fine but the `json` should look something like this for code to work:

```
[{
"id": 21441,
"description": "KENTUCKY FRIED CHICKEN, Fried Chicken, EXTRA CRISPY,Wing, meat and skin with breading",
"tags": ["KFC"],
"manufacturer": "Kentucky Fried Chicken",
"group": "Fast Foods",
"portions": [
{"amount": 1,
"unit": "wing, with skin",
"grams": 68.0}],
"nutrients": [{
"value": 20.8,
"units": "g",
"description": "Protein",
"group": "Composition"
},
{'description': 'Total lipid (fat)',
'group': 'Composition',
'units': 'g',
'value': 29.2}]}]
```

This is example with one record only.

Answer (score 0):

Amadan answered the question, but I managed to solve it like this prior to seeing his answer:

```
for i in range(len(db)):
    rec = db.loc[i]
    fnuts = pd.DataFrame(rec["nutrients"])
    fnuts["id"] = rec["id"]
    nutrients.append(fnuts)
```